# C# combining 2 string arrays into one with unique values

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, unions

This is related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506503/c-sharp-modifying-string-array-from-one-scope-level-down), but it seems different enough to post it separately:

I have settings that are stored in string arrays from user input (`DomAttributeIds` and `IntlAttributeIds`). I am trying to conditionally build an array of values to execute some code on. Conditions are:

1. If `DomAttributesSettings` exist, create an array of the values and pass them to the `AddAttributeEdit()` method.
2. If `IntlAttributesSettings` exist, create an array of those settings and combine them with the settings from condition one distinctly (no duplicates) and pass that array to the rest of the code, and ultimately each array element to the `AddAttributeEdit()` method.

The code below seems to work except for the "no duplicates" part. I thought using Linq's Union and/or Distinct methods would do this, but I must be doing something wrong. My code throws the following exception:

> Multiple controls with the same ID 'trAttribute_493' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.

I know that this is because that id exists in both settings. The `AddAttributeEdit()` method at the end contains code that builds a table and cells with Ids based on the values passed to it. What am I doing wrong to get a distinct union of the two arrays?

Here is the code:

```
    private void LoadAttributes()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DomAttributesSetting))
        {
            string[] attributeIds;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(IntlAttributesSetting))
            {

                string[] domattributeIds = DomAttributesSetting.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                string[] intlattributeIds = IntlAttributesSetting.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                IEnumerable<string> atrributeIdList = domattributeIds.Union(intlattributeIds).Distinct();
                attributeIds = atrributeIdList.ToArray();
            }
            else
            {
                attributeIds = DomAttributesSetting.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            } 
            foreach (string attributeId in attributeIds)
            {
                int attrId = -1;
                if (int.TryParse(attributeId, out attrId) && attrId != -1)
                {
                    Arena.Core.Attribute attribute = new Arena.Core.Attribute(attrId);
                    PersonAttribute personAttribute = (PersonAttribute)person.Attributes.FindByID(attribute.AttributeId);
                    if (personAttribute == null)
                        personAttribute = new PersonAttribute(person.PersonID, attrId);

                    AddAttributeEdit(attribute, personAttribute, true);
                }

            }


        }

    }...
```

Comment: Can I get a couple paragraphs?

Comment: @Austin Not sure what you mean.

Comment: If you can see the proposed edits, you will know I what I mean.

Comment: I think what Austin means is that your explanation at the top is a bit of an eyebender and could be split into paragraphs to make it more readable.

Comment: Gotcha, not sure what happend there. It looked fine in the edit mode, but came out "squishy". Thanks to zimdanen for fixing it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have padding around the values in the comma delimited lists (e.g "Prop1, Prop2" vs "Prop1,Prop2") or the casing is different.

Try trimming each value from the input and using a case-insensitive comparer like this:

```
var domattributeIds = DomAttributesSetting
    .Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(x=>x.Trim());

var intlattributeIds = IntlAttributesSetting
    .Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(x=>x.Trim());

var attributeIds = domattributeIds
    .Union(intlattributeIds, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    .ToArray();
```

You shouldn't even need to call `Distinct()` at the end.

Comment: The answer ended up being an error on my compiling rather than the actual code. I went ahead and marked this as the answer, though, as it got me to explore the use of 'var' which I had not used yet. I also like the technique of cleaning up the string and using ints to make it more robust.

Answer (score 1):

You must have different string representations of some ints - for example leading "0"s.

Your best bet is to convert to `int`s first, then run `Distinct`.

Something like:

```
var ints = attributeIds.Select( s =>
{
  int i;
  return Int32.TryParse( s, out i ) ? i : -1;
};

var uniques = ints.Where( i => i != -1 ).Distinct().ToList();

foreach ( int attrId in uniques )
{
  Arena.Core.Attribute attribute = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have two strings that vary only by case? Linq won't see those as duplicates by default. Try this instead:

```
domattributeIds.Union(intlattributeIds, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: that is a cool thought. In this case, however, I am using the exact same class on the exact same SQL data pool, so the arrays are being generated with the same format.

Comment: Without seeing the original strings, I'm out of ideas. Can you add them to your question?

Answer (score 1):

The following code will return the distinct string array from 2 string arrays

```
public string[] UniqueNames(string[] names1, string[] names2) {
    newName = names1.ToList();
    foreach (var dr in names2) {
        if (!newName.Contains(dr)) {
            newName.Add(dr);
        }
    }
    string[] newNameArray = newName.ToArray();
    return newNameArray;
}
```

or you can also try,

```
public string[] UniqueNames(string[] names1, string[] names2) {            
    return names1.Union(names2).ToArray(); ;            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Union from LINQ, for example:

```
string[] domattributeIds = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
string[] intlattributeIds = new string[] { "a", "c", "d" };

string[] combined = domattributeIds.Union(intlattributeIds).ToArray();
```

the new array "combined" has values "a", "b", "c", "d"

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. How is that different from what I am already doing in the first if section, aside from the fact that you combined them into a single call, where I broke it into a few pieces?

Comment: I did the same thing and got the exact result.. gmaness are you sure there are no additional white spaces in your strings? could you please print the strings out for us?

Answer (score 0):

```
 string a = "a,b, c";
 string b = "b,c,d";
 String[] ass  = a.Split( new char[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
 String[] bss =  b.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
 var list = ass.Union(bss).Distinct().ToArray();
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 foreach ( String s in list)
  {
    sb.Append(s);
  }
 Text = sb.ToString();
```

The final text is "ab ccd" because of the space. make sure your inputs dont contain spaces

Comment: can you not use .Trim() to remove the whitespace.

Comment: ofcourse I can.. I was just giving an example where apparently similiar stings can pass through the distinct() and union() calls